# How to control the number of column size for autogenerated fields gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a gridivew with auto-generated fields, whenever there is a new set of data coming in, i will append the grid with data. Is there a way to set a limited columns (e.g 6) so as to force user to navigate to the next page? instead of kept appending till it is super ugly?

Example:

[image]

thus, there could be Grade(12 July 2012), Grade(4 April 2013) and so on....

though i can find pagesize, but i cannt find columnsize!

Edited:

[image]

I manage to add a scrollbar at the bottom of the gridview. However the grid with auto-generated columns tends to be a little clustered. (if you notice the name column from second pic). Can any one help?

Code:

```
 <asp:Panel ID="ScrollPanel" style="Width:1300px;" runat="server" ScrollBars="Horizontal"> 
                    <asp:GridView ID="ViewAllHistory" runat="server" BorderWidth="1px" 
                        CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" AllowPaging="True" BackColor="Black" 
                        onpageindexchanging="ViewAllHistory_PageIndexChanging" PageSize="10">
                        <RowStyle BackColor="White"/>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                        <PagerSettings Position="TopAndBottom" />
                        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="White" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    </asp:GridView>
                    </asp:Panel>
```

it is only when i fix my gridview width then the design looks better. But i wouldnt want to fix my grid's width considering new set of data coming in. (long-term)

Comment: Do you want the first three columns to always be visible (and just page through the "`Grade [date]`" columns), or do you want to page through all the columns?

Comment: I want to page through all the columns, is it possible? because this could go on and on. the design would be like scroll further to the left instead having a "fix" position.

Comment: In this situation I'd wrap the table in a scrollable container with horizontal scrollbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Modify the columns collection**
One way to do this is would be to have all of the columns you're going to need already in your datasource, and then just modify the [`Columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns.aspx) collection of your `GridView`.  So, for instance, you have a button that adds a column, and you do this in it's click event:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BoundField newCol = new BoundField();
    // This string needs to be the name of the column in your datasource
    newCol.DataField = "Grade12July2012";
    // Whatever you want the column header to say
    newCol.HeaderText = "Grade(12 July 2012)";
    GridView1.Columns.Add(newCol);
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

**Use a scrollable `<div>`**
As [alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/999042/alex) said [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986504/how-to-control-the-number-of-column-size-for-autogenerated-fields-gridview#comment12764493_9986504), another way of doing this would be to just put a scrollable container around your `GridView`.  This way you can have all the columns there without taking up too much screen real estate:

```
<div id="gridContainer" style="width:200px; overflow:scroll; height:auto;">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">

    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Comment: i'll use a scrollable grid then, that should work. Thanks alot yeah.